# How to make the method run from the beginning Without using a Loop

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

The code in the `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menu = menu();
    if (menu == 0) {
        System.out.print("End program");
    }
    if (menu == 1) {
    
    }
    if (menu == 2) {
        System.out.print("Enter the Capacity>");
        double capacity = sc.nextDouble();
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            menu = menu();
            
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the `menu()` method:

```
public static int menu() {
    System.out.println("0. End program");
    System.out.println("1. No Caps");
    System.out.println("2. Knapsack Problem");
    System.out.println("3. Count Ways");
    System.out.println("4. Merge Strings");
    System.out.println("5. Password Generator");
    System.out.print("Enter a digit 0-5>");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    if (choice > 5 || choice < 0) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
        return menu();
    }
    return choice;
}
```

My problem is that I need the program to run from the **beginning** in case if use enters `capacity <= 0`.

Right now it's only printing the menu, but after I choose a menu option it exits even if `capacity <= 0`. I.e. the program is not checking if capacity is smaller than `0` again.

How can I fix that?

*I cannot use loops* - that is the requirement of my assignment.

Comment: https://www.educative.io/answers/goto-in-java

Comment: *not checking if capacity is smaller than 0 again* - you mean that the user input is `2` (*Knapsack Problem*) you need  and you the user enter the negative capacity you need the choice `2` to remembered and user should be asked to enter the capacity again instead of displaying the menu again?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I need it to reprint the menu and if the user choose option 2 again, I need it to  ask again to enter a new capacity.
in short, I need it to restart the program

Comment: Try putting the code from your main into a function and running that function when you need to reset.

Comment: @user16320675 its a school assignment , the requirements are not to use loops

Comment: @AliasCartellano I will try to do that , was actually thinking about doing it but I hoped there was a better solution for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not allowed to use loops, then you need to extract conditional logic into a separate method which will be called from the `main()`.

Lets call it `start()`. In case when the user provides a negative capacity for the `Knapsack Problem` (option `2`) we should invoke `start()` recursively.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    start();
}

public static void start() {
    int menu = menu();
    if (menu == 0) {
        System.out.print("End program");
    }
    if (menu == 1) {
    
    }
    if (menu == 2) {
        System.out.print("Enter the Capacity>");
        double capacity = sc.nextDouble();
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            start(); // calling `start()` recursively
        }
        System.out.println("Capacity: " + capacity);
    }
}

static int menu() {
    System.out.println("0. End program");
    System.out.println("1. No Caps");
    System.out.println("2. Knapsack Problem");
    System.out.println("3. Count Ways");
    System.out.println("4. Merge Strings");
    System.out.println("5. Password Generator");
    System.out.print("Enter a digit 0-5>");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    if (choice > 5 || choice < 0) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
        return menu();
    }
    return choice;
}
```